# I have some trouble pass an event to another function in my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

When I try get the event, I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

I'm trying to pass the `options` in the `Constructor Itoggle` to `mouseInOut` and then get `options` inside the `Itoggle.prototype.mouseInOut`. The code works fine before I try pass any arguments to `mouseInOut`, now I can't get the `event` anymore. Even if I try pass `event` as argument too or any argument.

The Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined makeup-itoggle.js:18
>   Itoggle.mouseInOut  makeup-itoggle.js:18
>   b.event.special.(anonymous function).handle
>   b.event.dispatch
>   v.handle

---

```js
;(function ($) {

  "use strict"; 

  var Itoggle = function (el, options) {
    $(el).on('mouseenter mouseleave', mouseInOut(event, options);
  };

  Itoggle.prototype.mouseInOut = function (event, options) {
    var $this = $(this)
      , selector = $this.attr('data-target')
      , target = $('#' + selector);

    var opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.itoggle.defaults, options);
    console.log(opt.titleActive); // ok

    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {//here's come the error. Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
      $this.addClass(opt.elementActive);
      $this.find('.nav-button-title').addClass(opt.titleActive);
      target.show();
    } 
    else if (event.type == 'mouseout') {
      $this.removeClass(opt.elementActive);
      $this.find('.nav-button-title').removeClass(opt.titleActive);
      target.hide();

      target.mouseenter( function () {
        $this.addClass(opt.elementActive);
        $this.find('.nav-button-title').addClass(opt.titleActive);
        target.show();
      });

      target.mouseleave( function () {
        $this.removeClass(opt.elementActive);
        $this.find('.nav-button-title').removeClass(opt.titleActive);
        target.hide();
      }); 

   } 
   else { console.log('invalid event'); }



 };

 /* ITOGGLE PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ========================= */

  $.fn.itoggle = function () {
    return this.each( function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('itoggle')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
      if (!data) { $this.data('itoggle', (data = new Itoggle(this, options)));}
    });
  };

  $.fn.itoggle.defaults = {
    elementActive: 'nav-outer-button-active',
    titleActive: 'nav-button-title-active'
  };

  $.fn.itoggle.Constructor = Itoggle;


})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: `event` needs to be passed into the actual event handler I guess...

Comment: @elclanrs I thought that could be this too, but when I do this I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a function result instead of function:

```
// wrong, function executes immediately,
// event is undefined atm, so it throws an error
$(el).on('mouseenter mouseleave', mouseInOut(event, options));

// correct way?
$(el).on('mouseenter mouseleave', mouseInOut);
```

Though I'm surprised that works. Normally, you have to pass a function like this:

```
$(el).on('mouseenter mouseleave', this.mouseInOut);
```

But apparently, if it works your way - then I'm wrong.

And remember that context of execution will be HTMLElement, which triggered the event, not an instance of `Itoggle`.

Comment: All you @monshq said was right. I changed how the handler is called to:
`$(el).on('mouseenter mouseleave', this.mouseInOut);`
and the error stoped. But my main question is how I can pass the object `options` to the `Itoggle.prototype.mouseInOut` ??

Comment: There's no way to do so afaik. JQuery accepts only one parameter in event handler from `.on()` function. You need to either patch this `.on()` function or set options in prototype `Itoggle.prototype.options`, if that suits your case.